# Two depending classes c++

Tags: c++

I made two classes: ClassA and ClassB that depends with each other. I prototyped ClassB so that the compiler would know there's an available ClassB. ClassA got compiled first then ClassB. So I would assume that the code below would work but the compiler says that ClassB is undefined even though I prototyped it. Now the question is... Why is it giving that error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassB;

class ClassA{
public:
    ClassA():x(50){}
    void printClassB(ClassB input){
        cout << input.y << endl;
    }

    friend class ClassB;
private:
    int x;
};

class ClassB{
public:
    ClassB(): y(100){}
    void printClassA(ClassA input){
        cout << input.x << endl;
    }

    friend class ClassA;

private:
    int y;

};



int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;

    b.printClassA(a);
    a.printClassB(b);

    cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide exact error message?

Comment: Generally speaking, circular dependencies are a sign of a design flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ClassA` to use `ClassB` then `ClassB` must be fully defined. Since the opposite is also true you can't really do that.

What you *can* do is use a *pointer* or *reference* to `ClassB` in `ClassA`, and then use the data from `ClassB` *after* you defined it.

Like

```
class ClassB;

class ClassA{
public:
    void printClassB(ClassB& input);

    ...
};

class ClassB { ... };

void ClassA::printClassB(ClassB& input)
    cout << input.y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yet should I avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1):

`ClassB` is anounced but not *defined* when you compile `ClassA`, so in `printClassB` function compiler doesn't know about `ClassB` member `y`. Move the functions out of classes, so they are compiled at the place where both classes are fully defined:

```
class ClassA{
public:
    ClassA():x(50){}
    void printClassB(ClassB input);

friend class ClassB;
private:
    int x;
};

class ClassB{
public:
    ClassB(): y(100){}
    void printClassA(ClassA input);

friend class ClassA;

private:
    int y;
};

inline void ClassA::printClassB(ClassB input){
    cout << input.y << endl;
}

inline void ClassB::printClassA(ClassA input){
    cout << input.x << endl;
}
```